# What is the base damage for fists?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know Khajiit get a bonus from their racial ability:

> Claws : Khajiit claws do 15 points of damage.

But what is the regular base damage for fists in Skyrim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the base damage for fists is 5.

I derived this but haven't tested it empirically.  I have found references to the bonus for Khajiit claws to be both 4x (Strategy Guide and other sites) and +15 (other sites).  That leads to this equation x+15=20 and that solves to x=5.

Comment: Or rather `x+15=4x`; from where did you get 20?